# How to implemet Dropbox Badge for Java Desktop App

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to implement Dropbox Badge for my Java Desktop Application - in the same way as it works for Microsoft Office. Does anybody know how to do this or give me a hint for further research? Thanks a lot.

[image: Dropbox Badge]